# Can't load font in Firefox when using addon domain

Tags: wordpress, firefox, dns, cross-domain, font-face

I've got WordPress installed on a domain, call it not-very-apealing-name-domain1.com. I also have an addon domain name, domain2.com which loads whatever is on located in the first domain. I noticed that when accessing the website using domain2.com fonts are not loaded in Firefox and the following error is displayed in the console:

`downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "CoolFont1" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed`

The font is 
The website and both domains are located at a web hosting service. How can I get the font to load?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
More details than you'll probably want to know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control
Probably solution: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: I suspected it could be that. Is there anything I can do if I don't have control of the web server? I have only ftp access.

Comment: The second link has an answer which mentions using `.htaccess` You should be able to edit that if your FTP client supports displaying hidden files.